# Why are some rake tasks missing?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

All of the `db:test:*` rake tasks are missing from my `rake -T` listing, but I am still able to call them normally. What could cause this?

Comment: I have tried supplying a pattern eg `rake -D db:test` or `rake -D test` but I still couldn't get rake to show the `db:test:*` tasks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the Rails team decided that `rake -T` gave too much output; many of the descriptions of the Rake tasks are commented out. See https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/29acc17 and https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9838156 for an example (which includes some tasks from `db:test:*`).

Answer (score 3):

I feel that they could have made a separate switch for listing all commands as well. But until that is done, I recommend using **rake -P** as it will list all the available commands and their dependencies -sadly without descriptions-, which is a bit overdoing the job. If you are on Linux like OS then using **grep** on the list will give you a more refined list.